# How can i stretch this image with multiple stretch points on IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, stretch

If you look at the image below, you can see that for it to stretch properly, i need two stretch points for the x-axis. basically at 25 and 75%, since i don't want the middle arrow to stretch.

On Android, i have done this with 9-patch of course, but from what i can see the only option to stretch in IOS is using the "stretchable" config in IB, or the

```
resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake
```

call.

My question is basically if i can get something similar to the multi-point stretch definition i get with 9patch, on IOS?

Image:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried Paintcode?

Comment: It's not possible if you want to keep the bottom arrow centered. I'd just make a custom view and draw it yourself or split the image into 3 parts.

Comment: @Do2 took a look, seems a bit too complex for what i'm trying to do, plus not free. thanks though

Comment: They have a trial, plus they have a tutorial video and they give an example on the exact thing you are trying to achieve..